# Checking if IP address is correct using RtlIpv4StringToAddressA and RtlIpv6StringToAddressA (C++). Convertion of data type problem

Tags: c++, ip

I am trying to create a function which returns a `BOOL` after checking if an IP address string is IPv4 or IPv6:

```cpp
static BOOL checkIp(CString strIPAddr)
{   
    BOOL result(FALSE);
    PCSTR ip = ((PCSTR)(PCTSTR)strIPAddr);
    PCSTR Terminator;
    in_addr aIpv4;
    in6_addr aIpv6;
    
    
    if ((RtlIpv4StringToAddressA(ip, true, &Terminator, &aIpv4) == STATUS_SUCCESS))
    {
        result = TRUE;
    }
    else if ((RtlIpv6StringToAddressA(ip, &Terminator, &aIpv6) == STATUS_SUCCESS))
    {
        result = TRUE;
    }

    return result;
}
```

In debug mode, after providing `127.0.0.1`, FALSE is returned. I think there is some problem with the data type: Error reading characters of String.

[image: Debug dialog]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a `PCTSTR` (`const TCHAR*`) to a `PCSTR` (`const char*`).  You are compiling for Unicode, so `PCTSTR` maps to `const wchar_t*`, not to `const char*` like you are expecting. That would explain why your debug window shows `ip` is just `"1"` and not `"127.0.0.1"`.

Get rid of the casts altogether, and use the `W` functions instead of the `A` functions.

```cpp
static bool checkIp(CString strIPAddr)
{   
    PCWSTR ip = strIPAddr;
    LPCWSTR Terminator;
    in_addr aIpv4;
    in6_addr aIpv6;
    
    return (
        (RtlIpv4StringToAddressW(ip, TRUE, &Terminator, &aIpv4) == STATUS_SUCCESS) ||
        (RtlIpv6StringToAddressW(ip, &Terminator, &aIpv6) == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    );
}
```

Comment: Logically it would be worth checking the length of `Terminator` also:

`return (RtlIpv4StringToAddressW(ip, true, &Terminator, &aIpv4) == STATUS_SUCCESS || RtlIpv6StringToAddressW(ip, &Terminator, &aIpv6) == STATUS_SUCCESS)  && _tcslen(Terminator) == 0;`

Comment: @msbit using `&& (*Terminator == L'\0')` would be simpler